# autoinstall options ignored on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, preseed, cloud-init

Have been using preseed to install systems for awhile and wanted to learn about autoinstall/cloud-init.  I was working through the example here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart and noticed that my installer doesn't download the cloud-init hosted on my webserver.

Installer loads, starts to install, but never downloads the config.  I've validated the webserver via wget and am monitoring the logfiles on it to see that there's no GET generated by the installer.  My iPXE config (adapted from the kvm example) is listed below.  What am I missing here?

```
#!ipxe

dhcp

initrd http://[...]/amd64/initrd.gz

kernel http://[...]/amd64/linux initrd=initrd.gz auto=true netcfg/choose_interface=${net0/mac} debian-installer/local=en_US keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us autoinstall net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ip=dhcp ipv6.disable=1 ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.187/
```

Comment: I didn't use `ipxe`, but with grub I had to escape the `;` character in the kernel arguments.  You can check to see if this might be the problem. Use `alt-f2` to get a console and use the command `dmesg | grep 'Command line'`.  You want the output to contain all the arguments, including `ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.187/`.  If the `;s=http://192.168.1.187/` part is missing, try escaping the `;`.  If everything is there, you can use the console to dig into `/var/log/installer` files.

Comment: Thanks for having a look!  From `/var/log/installer/syslog` file, I can see that `ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.187/` is there in cmdline.  Looking farther down the log, I can see that cloud-init gets installed.  I'll try to run cloud-init manually next.

Comment: Where are you getting the `initrd.gz` and `linux` files from?  If you were extracting them from the iso, I'd expect the names to be different.  The paths of your files makes me suspect you are using the legacy netboot files, which do not work with *autoinstall*.  You also have a combination of `debian-installer` and `subiquity` command line arguments. You are also missing a `url` argument for the live-installer iso.  Have you looked at the netbooting steps? https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510

Comment: Well thank you @AndrewLowther for pointing that out.  I just made the (obviously bad) assumption that the kernel/initrd bits for the ISO installer would be the same as the network installer.  I switched to the bits from the ISO and now it all makes sense.  You have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Also, I'm new to using StackExchange in general; is there a way for me to give you credit for your answer and/or does it matter? :-)

Comment: The credit doesn't matter.  Good luck with the autoinstall.  There are certainly some pitfalls and documentation isn't great.  There are some other questions on here that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew's comment regarding the different installers was the right thing.  I just made the (obviously bad) assumption that the kernel/initrd bits for the ISO installer would be the same as the network installer. I switched to the bits from the ISO and now it all makes sense.